# Remmina RDP connection problems

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, ubuntu-18.04, remmina

Good evening! Could anyone help me with my problem...
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on my local pc and I need to connect to a remote windows 8.1 pc by rdp, using a VPN.
I've managed to set up VPN as it shold be (MSCHAPv2, 128-bit with MPPE) and I can ping the remote machine (it's ip: 192.168.1.170)
I've set up latest Remmina for a rdp connection, filled all the connection parameters but **at the first connection attempt** I get such an error:

```
[23:04:24:341] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[23:04:24:354] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - creating directory /home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - creating directory [/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/certs]
[23:04:24:619] [10334:10620] [INFO][com.freerdp.crypto] - created directory [/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/server]
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = comp100
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - The hostname used for this connection (192.168.1.170:3389) 
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - does not match the name given in the certificate:
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - Common Name (CN):
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] -  comp100
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.crypto] - A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
[23:04:24:647] [10334:10620] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - The VerifyCertificate callback is deprecated, migrate your application to VerifyCertificateEx
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO failed with NTSTATUS: 0xC0000192
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x00020009]
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail
[23:04:36:788] [10334:10620] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

(org.remmina.Remmina:10334): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:04:36.934: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:8584: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

as far as i understand, the problem comes from a missing certificate that should be in a directory from log output:

```
/home/bajiepka/snap/remmina/3223/.config/freerdp/certs
```

further attempts shows almost similar error:

```
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[23:06:15:385] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[23:06:15:386] [10334:10667] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[23:06:15:435] [10334:10667] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
[23:06:15:435] [10334:10667] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = comp100
[23:06:15:462] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO failed with NTSTATUS: 0xC0000192
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED [0x00020009]
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail
[23:06:15:463] [10334:10667] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

(org.remmina.Remmina:10334): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:06:15.570: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:8584: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

can I generate this certificate manually, or did I miss anything about this certificate usage??? How can i solve this connection problem?